# How to enable brute force detection in keycloak using kcadm?

Tags: keycloak, brute-force, keycloak-rest-api

I need to enable brute force detection in security defences tab in keycloak, but i dont want to enable it manually is there way to do it using kcadm ???

thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via the REST API and therefore via `kcadm` when creating or updating the realm.

Check the [RealmRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/14.0/rest-api/index.html#_realmrepresentation) for such attributes as `bruteForceProtected`, `permanentLockout` etc.